# How to provide synchronization between interrupt context and process context

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, synchronization, interrupt-handling

I have small doubt regarding synchronization in the linux kernel i.e., what kind of locking technique is suitable  between interrupt context mode and process context to protect the critical region .

Thanks in Advance .....

Comment: I don't know about Linux specifically, but generally for most operating systems, there's a "dispatch needed" flag that is set if an interrupt handler sets a higher than current priority thread to ready. In this case, the interrupt handler exits via the dispatcher (for a context switch), instead of just returning. To deal with nested interrupts, there's also a flag used to keep track of which interrupt was the initial interrupt, so that only the initial interrupt optionally exits via the dispatcher (the nested ones would just return).

Comment: The important thing to keep in mind is that an interrupt handler cannot sleep; it has no task context. So if you need to need to synchronize a resource with the interrupt handler, you can't use a mutex or semaphore (those might sleep); it's got to be a spinlock or the equivalent. Which of course implies that you shouldn't hold the lock for long (and you can't do anything in task context that might block while holding it either).

Comment: Well, you can certainly post units to a semaphore.

Comment: Just to understand your question, are you trying to synchronize access to a resource which can be accessed in process context as well as irq context ? If yes, have you written some code. Can you post code that shows what you are trying to do. Because, there might a lot of things to look into before suggesting a solution.

Comment: Hi Vivek ,I was asked this question  in interview I have explained to him that spinlock is the correct option instead of mutex and semaphore but he didnt realize i have posted in SO to get more clarification .       The scenario is like " you have critical code which will be accessed between kernel thread and some ISR ,how to avoid data corruption which synchronization technique would help "

Answer (score 0):

hiya by definition solutions like: semaphors(or mutex), testandset and ofc spinlocks provide protection of critical code:
it's either by garunteeing an atomic operation (means locking for example will take exactly 1 operation to complete and aquire the lock, protocols such as the bakery protocol and disable preeamption of the proccess (and that's what you want) -once locked no one else can enter that critical code(let's say you used shared memory or something like that) so even if there IS a context switch and two threads run together we're Promised that only one can access that code, the thing is it's assumed all the threads that use that memory or w/e and have a critical region have the same type of lock aquire

for more info on spinlock (which disable peeamption of the CPU)
refer to this: http://www.linuxinternals.org/blog/2014/05/07/spinlock-implementation-in-linux-kernel/ 
notice that spinlock does a "busy wait" - means while the preeamption is enabled and you didn't aquire the lock the cpu "Wasting" calculation time on running in useless loop

you can also use the irq\preempt commands directly but that's pretty dangerous
eg:

```
 preempt_enable()       decrement the preempt counter
 preempt_disable()      increment the preempt counter
 preempt_enable_no_resched()    decrement, but do not immediately preempt
 preempt_check_resched()        if needed, reschedule
 preempt_count()            return the preempt counter
```

since i don't really know what you're trying to achieve it's kinda hard to go specific and answer your needs but i really dig sleepy semaphores: 
http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch09lev1sec4
unlike the rest of the solution i've offered they won't do busy wait which is saving calculation time.

i really hope i helped in this... gl!